# Date picker changing his layout

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker, android-dialogfragment

I'm having a problem with a datepicker in a project that I'm working. I was responsable for translate the project to English and Spanish, everything was okay until I test the application in the languages I was using. Everything is fine when the project is running in a device which language is Portuguese or Spanish, the datepicker stays fine, but when I change my cellphone to English the old datepicker from Android appears out of nowhere. I really don't know what to do.

[image: One]  [image: Two]

Comment: m having thew same issue, did u find the reason behind this?

Comment: which style you used for date piker?

Comment: Are you using the constructor with theme parameter when creating the DatePicker?